# How to stop whole process execution on exit(0) in child process?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

For the code snippet in the child process function with `exit(0)` log shows:
`[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-17] process exiting with exitcode 0`

```
def fetch_data():
   try:
       Do something
   except Exception as e:
       Log(e)
       exit(0)
```

How to kill the main process when above condition meets in child process?

Tried like below to propagate the signal from worker/ child to main process so that whole execution stops, but it's not working.

```
def initializer():
   signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(len(components_list), initializer=initializer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument to signal.signal is the handler for signal.  signal.SIG_DFL is the default handler for the action.  For signal.SIGCHLD this would be to ignore it.  You need to create a handler function that exits the process and pass that instead of signal.SIG_DFL.

From the docs:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIG_DFL

> signal.SIG_DFL
>
> This is one of two standard signal handling options; it will simply perform the default function for the signal. For example, on
> most systems the default action for SIGQUIT is to dump core and exit,
> while the default action for SIGCHLD is to simply ignore it.

```py
def exit_handler(signum, frame):
    print('Child exited')
    exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, exit_handler)
```

Comment: Hi @Ted, I tried this and did not work.

Comment: may be, I need to modify the func. def.